# Google Map API features enable

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

Does anyone know how you can enable the features like:Directions, Search nearby, save to map more? here you have a link so you can understand  better what I mean: http://screencast.com/t/h9HcTLy1

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

There is all explained

Comment: It doesn't say anything about how to enable features like:directions, search nearby and so on

Comment: I have not in mind very everything is exactly in the docu, but I know for sure that directions are explained under developers guide->Services->Directions. And the other stuff you will also find.